# Unable to login into private docker registry (v2.0)

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I am trying to setup a private Docker Registry using the standard docker registry image and a Docker Registry Reverse Proxy (https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/marvambass/nginx-registry-proxy/)

The goal is to secure the registry using SSL (using self-signed ssl cert) and username/password authentication. This all seems to go well, when i try to navigate via browser to private docker registry using : `https://<private-docker-reg>:443/v2/` I get a prompt to provide a username and password and i get correct output in this case `{}`

But when i try to login using the docker client i seem unable to login:

```
> docker login https://<private-docker-reg>:443 
> Username: foo
> Password: bar
> Email: 
> 
> FATA[0005] Error response from daemon: v1 ping attempt failed with
> error: Get https://<private-docker-reg>:443/v1/_ping: x509:
> certificate signed by unknown authority. If this private registry
> supports only HTTP or HTTPS with an unknown CA certificate, please add
> `--insecure-registry <private-docker-reg>:443` to the daemon's
> arguments. In the case of HTTPS, if you have access to the registry's
> CA certificate, no need for the flag; simply place the CA certificate
> at /etc/docker/certs.d/<private-docker-reg>:443/ca.crt
```

In trying to get around this issue i modified my `/etc/default/docker` file and added the following line on my docker client laptop:

`DOCKER_OPTS="$DOCKER_OPTS --insecure-registry <private-docker-reg>:443"`

Restarted the docker daemon, but no luck so far...

Any hints or tips to get around this issue??

Comment: check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39121710/not-able-to-login-in-docker-private-repositry/39245158#39245158) to setup private registry

Answer (score 0):

In order to use Docker Registry v2 you need to have at least docker client version 1.6.0 or higher. Run the following command to verify your docker CLI version:

```
docker info
```

As per docker registry documentation:

```
If a docker client has a version less than 1.6, Nginx will route its requests to the 1.0 registry. Requests from newer clients will route to the 2.0 registry.
```