# Not able to login in docker private repositry

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I configured insecure registry by self singed certificate.After providing user name and password , getting error message as **" Error response from daemon: Get https://ip address:5000/v1/users/: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority"**.

Comment: Did you also add the certificate to the daemon? See here for details: https://docs.docker.com/docker-trusted-registry/configure/config-security/

Comment: Yes, we added certificate to daemon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Execute following steps to docker registry with private certificates:

1. Generate private SSL Certificate with following command. This will create certs folder with two file domain.crt, domain.key

   ```
   openssl req -newkey rsa:4096 -nodes -sha256 -keyout certs/domain.key  -x509 -days 365 -out certs/domain.crt
   ```
2. Start docker registry with following command:

   ```
   docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --restart=always --name registry \
   -v `pwd`/certs:/certs \
   -e REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/certs/domain.crt \
   -e REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_KEY=/certs/domain.key \
   registry:2
   ```
3. On another machine where you want to pull the images, copy

   ```
   certs/domain.crt
   ```

   file to

   ```
   /etc/docker/certs.d/<<DockerRegistryServerHostname>>:<<DockerRegistryPort>>/ca.crt
   ```

   Make sure the name of certificate file is ca.crt (not domain.crt).

   For example, if docker registry IP address is docker.registry and port is 5000 then folder name will be

   ```
   /etc/docker/certs.d/docker.registry:5000/
   ```
4. Now run docker pull command. You should not face any issue.

Comment: This worked great when I was on digital ocean droplet but seems to be failing on amazon  ubuntu 18 e2c

Answer (score 0):

For CentOS7

nano /etc/pki/tls/openssl.cnf

and add

subjectAltName = IP:10.0.1.111

to Your [ v3_ca ] section

where IP is DockerRepositoryIP machine, then generate SSL key's again and send ca.crt to remote host that push image to repo..