# Private Docker registry error

Tags: linux, ssl-certificate, docker-registry, docker-image

I am new to docker and trying to push some images to `docker registry` which I made using self signed certificates.

docker push

```
<IP-Address>:5000/hello-world
```

But it gives following error:

The push refers to a repository

```
[<IP-Address>:5000/hello-world]
Get https://<IP-Address>:5000/v1/_ping: x509:
```

cannot validate certificate for

```
<IP-Address> because it doesn't contain any IP SANs
```

If I use Domain in place of IP-Address,
docker push

```
<domain-name.com>:5000/hello-world
```

it shows error:

The push refers to a repository

```
[<domain-name.com>:5000/hello-world]
Get https://<domain-name.com>:5000/v1/_ping: x509:
```

certificate signed by unknown authority

Am I missing something? How to solve this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39121710/not-able-to-login-in-docker-private-repositry/39245158#39245158) step by step guide to setup private registry. Hope this will help.

Comment: It solved my problem and was working fine but now I'm again getting the same problem `Certificate signed by unknown authority`. I am unable to push or pull images. Can you suggest something on it.

Comment: Please check the certificate file available on registry server and `/etc/docker/certs.d/<<DockerRegistryServerHostname>>:<<DockerRegistryPort>>/ca.crt` folder on client machine. This error comes only when the certificate is not properly copied. This issue may also occur if user does not have rights to access ca.crt file.

Comment: Also make sure you started the docker registry with command `docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --restart=always --name registry \
-v `pwd`/certs:/certs \
-e REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/certs/domain.crt \
-e REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_KEY=/certs/domain.key \
registry:2`. Make sure the path specified for `REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_CERTIFICATE` and `REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_KEY` parameter is correct

Comment: My platform is RHEL 7. There is no `etc/docker/certs.d folder`. Do I have to create `certs.d` folder or is there any other folder in Linux 7 ? What about copying `domain.crt` to `/etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/` ?

Comment: Please create `cert.d` folder inside `/etc/docker`. I have verified these steps on RHEL as well.

Comment: I have created and copied accordingly. But it is not working for me. It was working fine few days back but I tried to setup registry again and getting the problem: `certificate signed by unknown authority` even after I followed all steps.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add your certificate to the list of trusted certificates.

This is how you can do it in linux: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/90450/adding-a-self-signed-certificate-to-the-trusted-list

For other operating systems, just search for it.

To add the IP to your certificate, take a look at this tutorial https://jamielinux.com/docs/openssl-certificate-authority/ it's great!

You will have to add some alternative names to your certificate.

```
[alt_names]
DNS.1 = alternative.domain-name.com
IP.1 = 192.168.0.108
```

Comment: I did add `alt_names`. I am following https://deis.com/blog/2016/secure-docker-with-tls/. You can see if I miss anything.

Comment: You must add your cert.pem to your operating system trust store, or explicitly state it when starting the docker daemon like in the tutorial.

`--tlsverify --tlscacert=/etc/docker/ssl/ca.pem --tlscert=/etc/docker/ssl/cert.pem --tlskey=/etc/docker/ssl/key.pem"`

Comment: @ VolkerK I have `sample.keystore` , `sample.csr`, and `sample.cer` files. How to secure docker registry with these? How to get `sample.crt` and `sample.key` files from these?

Comment: I generated these `csr` and `keystore` using Java Keytool.